# Dynamic Programming problem help. Maximizing stair sum given a set number of steps

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have to create a dynamic programming solution to the following problem:

Given a set of n stairs, such that each step of the stairs has a positive value how can we maximize the value if we are allowed k steps up the stairs and we can choose to skip 1 or 2 steps at a time

Example:

Given arr: 5, 1, 6, 2, 8, 9  n=6

k = 3 we would take 6,8,9

k = 2 we would take 6,9

k = 1 we could not make it to the top of the stairs, furthest we could get is to value 6

k=n we would take all the steps

​

What's tripping me up is the fact that you have to take the last value (to make it to the top of the stairs) and you have to take values in such a way that you can actually reach the end. Any help, or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!

Update:

I was able to cache the recursive calls and reach O(n*k), not sure how to achieve a DP solution from here.

```
int myMem(int arr[], int n, int L)
{
count += 1;
if (L == 0 && n < 1)
    return 0;

if (L == n/3)
{
  if(mem[n-1][L] == 0)
    mem[n-1][L] = myMem(arr, n-3, L-1);
  return arr[n-1] + mem[n-1][L];
}

if (n < 1)
    return INT_MIN;

if (L > n/3)
{
    if(mem[n-1][L] == 0)
        mem[n-1][L] = myMax( myMem(arr, n-1, L-1), myMem(arr, n-2, L-1), myMem(arr, n-3, L-1));

    return arr[n-1] + mem[n-1][L];
}
return INT_MIN;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a naive recurrence that considers fixing each used step and taking the best of the possible steps that came before it. Note that the answer in that case is one of three (assuming there are at least three steps) since we can reach the top from either of the last three steps.

Top-down JavaScript code without memoisation (bottom-up left to the reader):

```js
function f(A, n, k){
  if (k == 0 && n < 1)
    return 0

  if (k == n / 3)
    return A[n-1] + f(A, n - 3, k - 1)

  if (n < 1)
    return -Infinity

  if (k > n / 3){
    return A[n-1] + Math.max(
      f(A, n - 1, k - 1),
      f(A, n - 2, k - 1),
      f(A, n - 3, k - 1)
    )
  }

  return -Infinity
}

var A = [5, 1, 6, 2, 8, 9]
var n = A.length
var k = 3

console.log(`A: ${A}`)
console.log(`k: ${k}`)
console.log(`max of (${f(A, n, k)}, ${f(A, n - 1, k)}, ${f(A, n - 2, k)})`)
console.log('')

k = 2

console.log(`k: ${k}`)
console.log(`max of (${f(A, n, k)}, ${f(A, n - 1, k)}, ${f(A, n - 2, k)})`)
console.log('')

k = 1

console.log(`k: ${k}`)
console.log(`max of (${f(A, n, k)}, ${f(A, n - 1, k)}, ${f(A, n - 2, k)})`)
```

Comment: I was able to modify your recursive approach to cache the recursive calls. I'm not sure how to jump to DP from here though.

Comment: @JeremyLeon if the recurrence works and makes sense, we can think of each call to `f` with a smaller `k` or `n` as a lookup in the DP table of a cell we already iterated on as we build bottom-up. If you can get the table initialised using the base case logic, you could then try to use the recurrence logic, assigning to the current cell.